# Capturing keys in Javascript temporarily disables scroll bar on scroll pad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery code to capture arrow keys (and the space bar).

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

When I invoke one of the buttons the scroll bar on my trackpad (laptop) is disabled for about 1 second. After one second it starts working again. Other keys (such as page up/page down) still work just fine. Why does the capture of these keys temporarily disable my trackpad's scroll bar? I don't have a mouse to test to see if it also disables the scroll wheel.

I am primarily using Firefox 42 on Ubuntu but confirmed this is also an issue in Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

The keys `38` and `40` are for up and down and when you are pressing them, you are using `e.preventDefault()`, which will not allow that to happen. So you don't see your page moving up or down.

Maybe, your trackpad's scrollbar fires the same events as up and down, but in a different way. The Page Up and Page Down aren't affected as you are not binding them.

Comment: I set up a test using `alert("Up/Down Pressed")`. It only triggers for the up and down arrow keys and doesn't get triggered for using the trackpad's scrollbar.

Comment: @kojow7 That's really confusing... Can you tell what is your trackpad company or model?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's built into an Acer Aspire 5742.